# How to run method that returns an object of "Type" from generic class

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, typeof

Could you help me with a problem. I want to initialize and use such a class:

```
public class GenericClass<T>
{
    public static T Method(string xml)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

What I want to do is:

```
public void do(Type _type)
{
    var genObj = new GenericClass<_type>();  // Error
    var result = genObj.Method("parameter");
}
```

I have found how I can initialize GenericClass [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059272/c-sharp-how-to-initialize-generic-class-with-object-of-type-type) , but I don't really know how can I run method of this instance which returns a type used in initialization.

Comment: Please observe the `MakeGenericType` that binds _type as the T and returns you a Type "containing" materialized generic class definition. Then, Activator.CreateInstance does the trick, as for any Type.

Comment: I suppose a follow up question might be, what problem are you trying to solve with this solution?

Comment: I found the way to create generic class, but I am not sure how can I run method and get result from it. Result should be of the same type as I am using for class creation.

Comment: `_type` has a value known only at runtime. The type parameter `<T>` must be known (for any concrete type) at compile time. So, what you're asking simply isn't possible because it requires information prior to the moment in time when it's available.

Comment: Hi. Why did you set "duplicate" on this question? The answer you provided link to can not help to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are actually asking is how you can create dynamic instances of `GenericClass<T>` by using reflection. This is how it works:

```
var genericTypeDefinition = typeof(GenericClass<>);
var concreteType = genericTypeDefinition.MakeGenericType(_type);
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(concreteType); // Calls default constructor.
```

If you want to call some `instance.Method()`, you'll have to cast the instance to a more specific type (since `CreateInstance` simply returns an object). I would suggest that you define an interface that defines this method, have the `GenericClass<>` implement this interface, so that you can safely cast to this interface at runtime and call the desired method:

```
interface ISomeInterface
{
    object Method(string xml);
}

class GenericClass<T> : ISomeInterface
{
    void object ISomeInterface.Method(string xml)
    {
        return Method(xml);
    }

    public T Method(string xml)
    {
    }
}
```

and then:

```
var genericTypeDefinition = typeof(GenericClass<>);
var concreteType = genericTypeDefinition.MakeGenericType(_type);
var instance = (ISomeInterface) Activator.CreateInstance(concreteType); // Calls default constructor.

instance.Method("parameter");
```

Comment: Method should return a result of type T. That was a point of the question.

In your case it will be generic interface too: T Method(string)

Comment: Yes, it occurred to me. Changed that now.